# Order by before Group by with subquery

Tags: php, mysql

I know there is a lot of questions about subqueries. I have read a lot of them and tried to use the answer to my needs but for some reason I can't make it work.

My table contains list of results from exercises. 
"bruger_id" is the users id
"prog_oevelse_id" is the id of the exercise
"kg_km" is how many kg the user has lifted or distance
"reps_tid" is how many times the user has lifted the amount of kg or how many minutes he used.

This is my table:

[image]

I need it to list the users results where he has performed best but only one per exercise. I have tried with:

```
$results = $pdo->query("
          SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT * FROM myw_resultat 

            ORDER BY kg_km DESC
          ) t
        WHERE bruger_id = '$user_id'
        GROUP BY prog_oevelse_id
        ");
```

But when I echo the query above with:

```
$SL = 0;
        foreach($results as $key => $row) { 

        echo $row['prog_oevelse_id'];
        echo " - ";
        echo $row['kg_km'];
        echo " / ";
        echo $row['reps_tid'];
        echo "<br>";
        }
```

it gives me this results:

[image]

My expected output is:

[image]

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: How you define `"perform best"` more kg more reps?

Comment: You shouldn't save kg and km on the same column. Because if two people lift the same weight but one do more reps than the other he perform better. Then if two people run the same distance the one with the least time perform better.

Comment: Samir: I have added my expected output.

Comment: Juan Carlos: It's a comparison of his own performance. I will take notice of your suggestion to seperate the columns kg_km and reps_tid.

Comment: Same thing if you compare with yourself. Which one is better the one where you lift more weight or the one you did more reps. For weight better performance shoudl be `kg*rep` for distance would be `km / time`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $pdo->query("
        SELECT R.prog_oevelse_id, R.kg_km, R.reps_tid
        FROM myw_resultat R
        JOIN ( SELECT prog_oevelse_id, MAX(kg_km) as m_kg_km
               FROM myw_resultat 
               WHERE bruger_id = '$user_id'
               GROUP BY prog_oevelse_id ) as M
          ON R.prog_oevelse_id = M.prog_oevelse_id
         AND R.kg_km = M.m_kg_km
        WHERE R.bruger_id = '$user_id'
```

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm. :-)

Comment: as for my other comment you should change `MAX(kg_km)` for `MAX(kg*rep)` and `MAX(km/time)` to get a better definition of better performance

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem for order by, it's a problem with you not using aggregate functions.

```
select
    prog_oevelse_id,
    max(kg_km) as kg_km,
    reps_tid
from
    myw_resultat
where
    bruger_id = 1
group by
    prog_oevelse_id,
    reps_tid
order by
    prog_oevelse_id asc
```

That `max()` call will get the highest value for a column inside a grouped statement.

Further reading: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: how you guarantee the reps_tid correspond to the max(kg_km)?

Comment: Because it's in the group by clause :) Or at least it was supposed to be - I typo'd earlier and forgot the _tid